# Reopen and clean this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'd like to see [Does Arduino use C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812850) reopened and given a spring cleaning.

I ran across it because a friend sent me the link and I was dismayed by the comment thread (and the dreadful -12 answer, voted to delete). I think the question is valid and the good answers are good, and it appears as though enough people found it useful to not suffer the ignominy of closure.

(Also fine if it's migrated to Arduino if it doesn't break the Google search.)

Comment: Just a quick note: questions cannot be migrated even by mods if it's older than 60 days.

Comment: That question is either too broad (asks multiple questions) or opinion based (what should I learn). It is fine as it is, it doesn't need to be re-opened. Get rid of the comments and be done with it.

Comment: *"I think the question is valid"* - What makes you think it's valid?  ----- *"the good answers are good"* - Good for them, that's irrelevant though, good answers don't make good questions

Comment: I vote to either historically lock it or delete it, and preferably the latter for just being trash we don't really need on the site.

Comment: @Nick Because the bulk of the question is asking "Is it C or C++", which is a reasonable question to ask (and is asked surprisingly often).

Comment: @rene The bulk of the question is not that opinion part, the rest is "What does it use" and some miscellaneous noise.

Comment: I'm starting to be convinced it's not a good question as-is; there's more noise in there than the question title indicates. I edited out the cruft.

Comment: The question, with all fluff removed is: *"I see in one place that Arduino uses 'standard' C, and in another that it uses 'standard' C++. Which is it?  -- How does that affect which language or dialect (C or C++) should I concentrate on learning for use primarily with Arduino?"*, the first is trivially look-up-able and the real meat is the second half, which is opinion based. I'm certain it _could_ be edited to not be opinion based, but as it stands I'm not convinced.

Comment: @Nick Except that if you use Google it's the first result (for me, for algorithmic reasons :) and it shows the deleted answer :/

Comment: @DaveNewton Fair. Your edit clearly makes the question not opinion based..., it doesn't necessarily make it _useful_. But it's certainly not off-topic now

Comment: @Nick Also fair :) I think it's both useful and reasonable, if only because it's currently a canonical search result.

Comment: @AndrewT. Right. I continue to forget that :/

Comment: I think the question might be a candidate for historical lock

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wasn't entirely sure if a historical lock should be applied here, but since one of those who voted to reopen the question has flagged asking for one, I'll trust them. The question and its answers look good now, and I don't see a reason it needs to go away.

Comment: Uh... maybe I should've edited the accepted answer first. Never mind, good thing I'm a mod.